# Git PR shows only commits and no files

Tags: git, github

I have a PR from branch1 to branch2. In the PR, I see two commits but there are no files shown as differences. I am not sure what this means? Can anyone help me understand the same?

Comment: It can mean that your branches are equal

Comment: If you are using GitHub, you can see the differences by clicking on the commit in PR.

Comment: I don't say it *is* the case, but a commit and its *revert commit* would cancel each other and produce this empty PR. But of course this is just speculation. Inspect each commit's changes to know.